# How to print or to write in a file the output of convolutional layer in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Code:

```
conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
# Max Pooling (down-sampling)
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(conv2))
```

- I have used this but I am getting the following error message:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value
>   for placeh older tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
>            [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/j ob:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Answer (score 1):

`conv1` was generated as result some operation on the placeholder tensor. You should feed data to the call `sess.run(conv2)`. Example of `tf.placeholder` from [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder):

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1024, 1024))
y = tf.matmul(x, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(y))  # ERROR: will fail because x was not fed.

    rand_array = np.random.rand(1024, 1024)
    print(sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: rand_array}))  # Will succeed.
```

Comment: arr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,7*7*64))
 
    with tf.Session() as sess:
 
        print(sess.run(conv2, feed_dict={arr: conv2}))

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand what is it?

Comment: after using `with tf.Session() as sess:
        rand_array = np.random.rand(None,7*7*64)
        print(sess.run(conv2, feed_dict={conv2: rand_array}))`  i am still getting error :***TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer***

Comment: can you please tell me how to convert a tensor flow variable to a normal python variable.??

Comment: rand_array = np.random.rand(None,7*7*64)  you can't create numpy array with undefined dim.